# I want to notify when asp.net product price drops

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a sales site that I developed with c# asp.net mvc. On this site, the user can track the product. When the product price decreases by the admin, I want to notify the user if there is a product with a reduced price among the products followed by the user. Is there a build I can use? Where can I start?

As a result of my research, I found a structure called signalr. Do you have this or a similar structure?

Comment: Its a little vague.  Are you only interested in notifying the user with the website open?  signalr will work only when they are connected to the site - what happens if they are offline?  You have 2 roles at play here - admin and user..  Sounds like you need a little thought into the mechanism.  Perhaps trigger some background processing and write a result away (database or something) - where it can be retrieved later if they are offline.

Comment: It does not matter whether the user is online or offline, it has to work both ways.

Comment: Have a look at SignalR or web sockets - will be a good choice of when a user is connected.  Beware there are 2 versions of SignalR - depending if you are DotNetFramework or DotNetCore. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-7.0.  You probably need another mechanism to deliver a message for when they are back online.